# How to fix DI\\DependencyException" in Slim Framework?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, slim

I am using slim framework. But when i refresh the page i got the following error. My all paths are correct but still getting this error.

```
{
    "message": "Slim Application Error",
    "exception": [
        {
            "type": "DI\\DependencyException",
            "code": 0,
            "message": "Error while injecting dependencies into App\\Action\\User\\UserListDataTableAction: No entry or class found for 'App\\Domain\\User\\Service\\UserListDataTable'",
            "file": "/opt/lampp/htdocs/slim/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Definition/Resolver/ObjectCreator.php",
            "line": 147
        },
        {
            "type": "DI\\NotFoundException",
            "code": 0,
            "message": "No entry or class found for 'App\\Domain\\User\\Service\\UserListDataTable'",
            "file": "/opt/lampp/htdocs/slim/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Container.php",
            "line": 135
        }
    ]
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Action\User;

use App\Domain\User\Service\UserListDataTable;
use App\Responder\JsonResponder;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

final class UserListDataTableAction
{

    private $userListDataTable;

    private $responder;

  
    public function __construct(
        UserListDataTable $userListDataTable,
        JsonResponder $responder
    ) {
        $this->userListDataTable = $userListDataTable;
        $this->responder = $responder;
    }
}
```

[image]

Please guide me where i am wrong.

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: The last part of the message seems to point to `UserListDataTable` not being found.

Comment: Try to run phpstan for example with: `composer phpstan`

Comment: @odan very helpful command. Thanks

Comment: @RobinSingh So could you solve the issue?

Comment: @odan , No error still there. let me add screenhot then you check

Comment: According to the screenshot the path `... DomainBase/__boiler/...` is not correct. The correct PSR-4 compatible path would be `src/Domain/User/Service/UserListDataTable.php`

Answer (score 0):

I had a project in **Slim4 Framework**.

My folder structure where the **file I wanted to execute** was `src/Domain/BlogPost/Service/SinglePostReader.php`

In `SinglePostReader.php` I had a namespace `App\Domain;` *(and that was obviously wrong)*.

So in my `src/Action/BlogPostAction.php` file, I had a constructor:

```
public function __construct(SinglePostReader $singlePostReader)
    {
        $this->singlePostReader = $singlePostReader;
    }
```

And when I executed the `BlogPostAction class` through my router.php it gave me an exception:

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details
Type: DI\DependencyException
Code: 0
Message: Error while injecting dependencies into App\Action\BlogPostAction: No entry or class found for 'App\Domain\SinglePostReader'
File: /var/www/slim_new/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Definition/Resolver/ObjectCreator.php
Line: 147
```

---

**To resolve this**, I tried to **change my namespace** in `SinglePostReader.php` to `App\Domain\BlogPost\Service;` so the namespace had the exact folder structure
`src/Domain/BlogPost/Service/SinglePostReader.php`.

And in my `BlogPostAction.php`:
`use App\Domain\BlogPost\Service\SinglePostReader;`

**That solved my problem!**
I hope this helps someone!

Cheers!